# Different links under 'My Links' and 'My Site - My Links' for different web applications

Tags: 2007, my-site

I work with Sharepoint 2007 and have the following problem:

I have two web applications (foo.domain.com and bar.domain.com) each with one site collection. When I browse with IE through foo.domain.com, I can view and add sites to the 'My Links' drop down menu. These links also can be managed via 'My Site' - 'My Profile' - 'Links'. So far so good.

But if I browse through bar.domain.com, I got different links under the 'My Links' menu. even if i click 'add to My Links', this "new" link only shows up in the my links section when I browse through foo.domain.com and not when i browse through bar.domain.com.

Months ago, these 'My Links' list was not treated differently, but I have no idea what has changed since then. Any ideas what to change or where to look at? thx a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

When you create an SSP you setup a mapping between your web applications and the SSP(s).  If you are seeing different information, then it sounds like you have multiple SSPs and the sites are mapped to different ones.

If you log into CA and click on Shared Services you will see the mappings.  Changes can be made from there.